# Visualforce Totals Not Updating After Save

Tags: visualforce

I've created a visualforce page and custom controller to allow users to enter a number that is recorded on their user record on their own. Working fine however after updating a users number the totals at the bottom of the page don't recalculate until the custom Tab they use to access the page is clicked again. How can I have it so that when they hit save the page updates the totals as well?

```
//Visualforce Page
```

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!u}" var="users">
        <apex:Column value="{!users.Name}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Rep Commit" ><apex:inputField value="{!users.Rep_Commit__c}"/>
            <apex:facet name="footer">
                <apex:outputText value="{0, number, $###,###,###.00}">
                    <apex:param value="{!repCommitTotal}"/>
                </apex:outputText>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Manager Commit" rendered="{!IF(OR($Profile.Name = 'System Administrator',$Profile.Name = 'Strategy Team', $Profile.Name = 'Sales Manager'),true,false)}" ><apex:inputField value="{!users.Commit_Manager_Override__c}"/>
        <apex:facet name="footer">
            <apex:outputText value="{0, number, $###,###,###.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!mgrCommitTotal}"/>
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:facet>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

```
 // Controller 
public class CommitEntryController {
    public List<User> u {get;private set;}
    public decimal repCommitTotal{get;set;}
    public decimal mgrCommitTotal{get;set;}

    public CommitEntryController(){
    repCommitTotal = 0;
    mgrCommitTotal = 0;

    u = [SELECT Id, Name, Rep_Commit__c, ProfileId, Commit_Manager_Override__c 
         FROM User 
         WHERE (IsActive = TRUE OR Rep_Commit__c > 0 OR Commit_Manager_Override__c > 0) 
         AND (Position__c = 'GM' OR Position__c = 'AE' OR Position__c = 'KAL' OR Position__c = 'AM')
         AND (Id =:UserInfo.getUserId() OR Manager.Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()) 
         ORDER BY Name ASC];

    if(u.size()>0){
        for(User uTotals : u){
            repCommitTotal = repCommitTotal + uTotals.Rep_Commit__c;
            mgrCommitTotal = mgrCommitTotal + uTotals.Commit_Manager_Override__c;
            }
        }
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        update u;
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('apex/CommitEntry?sfdc.tabName=01r1h000000Cl61');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to perform a [Partial Page Update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_ajax_partial_page_updates.htm).

You'll need to add a `rerender=[id goes here]` attribute on the `<apex:commandButton>` that calls `save()`, and apply that same ID value to your `<apex:pageBlockTable>`. This instructs Salesforce to rerender these elements within the page when the server action completes.

Note that additionally you will have to recalculate your total data to have the updated values displayed. You're currently doing this in your constructor, so you may want to factor that code out into a new method that you'd also call in your `save()` method.

Comment: Thanks David! Got it work using your advice. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

my proposed solution. just use rerender and give ids to everything you want to re-render

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BXHWIA4

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/87359)

Comment: i answered the solution in plain text and gave a link to someone implementing the solution.